# Change Password using react native and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

In our project there is an option that the user can change their password. To do that

1. Before change the password user must enter current password, then check whether the entered password is matched with the saved password right now.
2. If it is OK, Then User has to update the old password (saved password) with new password.

I am using react native and Firebase for the developing of the project. If any one knows the solution, please let me know...

[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific question? You should break this task down and work in the different pieces. If you then have some specific questions come back and ask them and supply some example code the explain your problems.

Answer (score 11):

Firebase Auth won't let you change a password unless you are recently authenticated. If you try to `updatePassword` without being recently authenticated, you will get an error `auth/requires-recent-login`. 
Here is how you can do it:

```
// Ask signed in user for current password.
const currentPass = window.prompt('Please enter current password');
const emailCred  = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    firebase.auth().currentUser, currentPass);
firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(emailCred)
    .then(() => {
      // User successfully reauthenticated.
      const newPass = window.prompt('Please enter new password');
      return firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePassword(newPass);
    })
    .catch(error = > {
      // Handle error.
    });
```

Note the above example, uses `window.prompt` for illustration. You would use your own equivalent react-native UI here instead.